# Bootstrap4 DatePicker Disable Hour Selection and set Default Hour

Tags: flask, bootstrap-4

I want to set datePicker HH:mm always have 09:00AM. I managed to disable hour picker.

HTML

```
<input class="form-control" id="date_start_picker">
```

JS

```
function initDatePicker(id_picker, date, id_other_picker, is_first_picker = true, format = 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm') {
  let this_object = this
  var datePicker = $(id_picker)
  datePicker.datepicker({
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
    modal: false,
    footer: false,
    value: date,
    format: format,
    minDate: "2000-01-01"
  });
}
```

There is nothing mentioned in documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve my desired result by doing below

```
change: function (event) {
  let picker_value = datePicker.val()
  if (picker_value.includes('00:00')) {
    picker_value = picker_value.replace("00:00", "09:00")
    $(datePicker).datepicker("value",picker_value);
  }          
}
```